# Facebook Debugger - "Error Parsing URL"

Tags: facebook, debugging, parsing, url

i have searched a lot for solutions for this problem. Since none of the solutions i have found worked for me i am posting my experience with this issue to see if i can get some help.

Theres this site that i worked on some time ago and it always worked fine to share links on facebook and to use facebook like button. The OG tags are set up as i usually add them on every project i work on, but i have never had this problem before.

Check out how the source code that is being displayed on the browser after the page is loaded (url: http://www.estanaweb.com.br):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="289790431108540" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_br" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.estanaweb.com.br" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ESTANAWEB" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Eventos Vips de Porto Velho" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.estanaweb.com.br/wp-content/uploads/logo-estanaweb-facebook.png" />
```

All informations on the OG tags are valid and correct. A few things i have tried:

- Checking the time spent on db queries to see if the facebook connection was timing out
- Checking if the data on the tags are correct
- Checking if the site is on Blacklists
- Makin a html page only with the OG tags
- Ordered the OG tags in many different orders
- Removed all the OG tags
- Add the tags, one by one and the main by theirselves
- Deleted my .htaccess
- Setup my .htacess in different ways
- I didn't get any error saying the url was spam or anything like that either

Anyway, my point is that i tried a lot of things and i still get the parsing url error.

Any hints on whats going on anyone?

Sorry if my english is somewhat bad, its not my main language.

Thx in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have a DNS problem to fix first:

```
$ host www.estanaweb.com.br
www.estanaweb.com.br has address 189.113.11.82
Host www.estanaweb.com.br not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Host www.estanaweb.com.br not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

FB is not able to crawl it reliably probably.  This is what my host sees:

```
$ wget http://www.estanaweb.com.br/
--2012-08-16 14:15:21--  http://www.estanaweb.com.br/
Resolving www.estanaweb.com.br (www.estanaweb.com.br)... failed: hostname nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.estanaweb.com.br'
```

Comment: I have opened a support ticket about it on my host, i'll wait the answer to see if that was the only issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: It was really just the DNS problem. I didn't even dream of this issue being the DNS since i was able to access the website and didn't find anyone else who reported something like this. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.